# pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If anybody can explain me this? How i get these decimal values and whats the meaning of **np.random.randn(6,4)** ?

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2013-01-04  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
2013-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
2013-01-06 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
```

Comment: First question: did you read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)? Second question: did you understand the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `np.random.randn` returns random float values of normal distributions with mean = 0 and variance = 1. Now `np.random.randn` takes shape you would like to return of those distributions.

For example:

`np.random.randn(1,2)` returns an array of one row and two columns. Similarly, you can give `np.random.randn(1,.,.,.,9)` which gives you out a complicated array. Since you have mentioned `np.random.randn(6, 4)` it returned you 6 rows and 4 different columns.

For documentation refer: [Check this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)